# Throwing error from subscription/observable - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am attempting to throw an error from my observed function, such that I can access the `err` part of my subscription, but I cannot seem to get through to that part.

Comment: What is "return throwError(res);"

Comment: It is from `import {throwError} from 'rxjs/index';`

Comment: Use return throwError(new Error(res));

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya - I still can't get the `component.errorMessage` to be seen as what I expect :-/

Comment: Try to recreate this with a simplified example on stackblitz or plunkr - will be much easier for people to help.

Comment: How do you know that it is not working? Your test won't work that way because you call an asynchronous function, that means you cannot assert the properties without waiting for the observable to be complete.

Comment: It is very brief, but: https://stackblitz.com/edit/error-throwing-from-subscription-test

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it via the map way, but here is a different way:

```
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getObs().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  getObs() {    
    const observable = of(6);
    const isError = true;
    if (isError) {
      return throwError("Is an error!");
    }
    return observable;
  }
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqp4qv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways I would handle this. Heres one way using **_throw**

```
// auth.ts
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';

login( username, password ) {

    const body = this.jsonifyData( username, password );

    return this.http.post<any>( this.apiBaseUrl + '/auth', body )
        .pipe(
        map( res => {
            if ( 'token' in res ) {
                return res.token;
            }
            // Unsuccessful login returns error
            return _throw( res ); // from import {_throw} from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
        } )

    );
}
```

The other would be to just catch the error in the login component

Answer (score 0):

I think in your component's test spec you need to mock up your `authService` and the `login` procedure. This mock does not make http call, just throw an error via `throwError(new Error('Either username or password were incorrect'))` immediately if, say, password does not match some predefined value. [Here](http://www.zackarychapple.guru/angular2/2016/11/25/angular2-testing-services.html) is some example of how to test component-http service stuff, it is a bit outdated but still actual conceptually.